# Spring-Batch Reader, Processor and Writer

Tags: mysql, csv, google-cloud-storage, spring-batch, batch-processing

I need to create a Spring Batch job that reads various data from MySQL, puts this data into a .csv file, and then sends this file to Google Cloud Storage.

I would like to understand the architecture. For instance, I have a reader that will read the data from MySQL and transform it into a certain domain. After that, I need to create a .csv file to store this data. At this stage, should I use the writer or the processor? I am unsure because, after this step, I need to send this file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, which I believe involves a writer as well. Could you provide a more professional perspective to help me navigate through my project.
Could someone show me a simple example of this implementation for me to follow? I'm lost and I don't know where to go.
Thanks

I've tried a few approaches, but I'm not succeeding. I have doubts; do I need 2 steps? For example, one reader to read from MySQL and one writer to transform the data into a .csv file. And another step with one reader reading this file and another writer writing it to the Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep things simple and do it in two steps:

- Step 1 (chunk-oriented): reads data from MySQL, transforms it as needed, and writes it in a csv file
- Step 2 (simple tasklet): copies the file to GCP (no reader or writer needed here, just a file upload operation)